# What am I trying to say?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher

[image]

This is an enigmatic puzzle. The puzzler must deduce what kind it is and solve it with no help.

Comment: (You may want to consider some way of rendering this in a text form, as there are users here who cannot readily distinguish colors.)

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/1UEK3

Comment: Props to whoever gets the RGB values of everything in here

Comment: You can extract the RGB values directly from the saved pic file, but I doubt it's related to the exact values. Probably more like rainbow-spectrum related. Just a guess.

Comment: @DavidFoong feelinferrety to the rescue!

Answer (score 6):

## DATA DUMP

### Letters

For the colorblind or anyone having issues reading some letters, or indeed, anyone who simply wanted a transcription:

```
K L O   A Z Y   C P T
N E Y   W S E   I G Z
Y C Z   N V S   C T M

U C B   O F A   Y O W
B T V   T B Y   W G H
Z X S   U G J   S I B

Y L U   X U Q   A S U
E V N   Q J A   M I R
P V C   X Q S   B B X
```

### Colors

The following code block contains the colors used in the puzzle image in *HEXADECIMAL* format. In case it is not immediately obvious, format is as follows:

**Stacked items**

```
Color of letter
Color of background
```

There is one pair of stacked items in each member of the 3x3 set:

```
A1  A2  A3

B1  B2  B3

C1  C2  C3
```

The full 9x9 also follows the above format, with increased spacing between 3x3 blocks.

```
19ea7f 2981c8 6d17ca        3c8357 2d21d8 231121        9afe34 68dbd9 9dcfbe
1de0c8 8cf73c dd61ec        7ab7d7 e8621f ce37e1        8bcd3f 3d2a99 db8bcd

a3f8c8 85c0fa 85139c        76fcb3 c4d4d9 deac16        a2c17b b6458d eccd31
59bcb2 39235e 36c144        b10b42 244485 0397c8        b84546 b2dbdc 2b82e8

57690e 15e60d 6a3e92        4e3229 8e2d89 eff68f        635aef 594111 344a98
a63811 bceda6 d693c2        8578db 682201 88c331        ab0da3 1f8461 5ecfef


6da1f1 7119d8 2836ab        4e4314 0cecd5 252593        3a4b7c d60bc0 4ebb46
cfccc0 770634 ecea3d        18814c 1ddb45 fd6c83        cce73e c1c8e5 6c67a5

a0c70c 9e30ec 940399        2e47d3 e66fdd 88fc3b        9b5b61 492756 9b06ee
91d2bf 776670 1f7d90        81915c fd9a34 f726b8        a04dcc b86aae 38ba35

5e9434 c50d97 c46adf        aafa05 d904a2 7ec2f3        4c05d2 cd6b67 01a08f
522721 8642b4 c4c42b        ff2371 ea9f3b 5c0ba4        3d255d 4add38 88c03f


b7ec2c d6acf1 80a9a7        ce759e c39589 0a1231        9784ae d7a473 0db825
11dc13 65eca2 1b12f6        9fd987 c5416a 2ccc57        534c81 df08d0 87f876

cdf3bb 9ba9af 31cc8a        0519a4 542be1 f576b8        fb1c81 670fa3 a034ac
f40954 57e2ed 1f52fb        b8eede 2a1aba af952c        264e51 4ab294 cb13ea

05936d 9d8049 5c1e0e        94f578 873b46 534879        095dd8 8e2c52 de3037
561e9b 7107a8 31a334        4c4bd1 b89847 98cd3f        76658d 147243 49e4cb
```